# SQL 2008 SP1 crashing almost daily

Tags: sql-server-2008, windows-server-2008-r2

almost every day our new DB crashes. It is virtual server residing on same hardware as 5 other servers, two of them beeing identical MS SQL2008sp1 and two Oracle 11g's so I can pretty much rule out hardware issues.

Server has dedicated local LUN, 4vCPU and 8GB memory with 2GB windows swap file. It runs 4 instances. Primary instance is limited to 5GB memory and paralelism set to 4 running on MS SQL 2008 SP1 @ Windows Server 2008 Enterprise R2 x64.

Only that primary instance is crashing. After it crashes nothing can connect to it, it's even impossible to shut it down through service manager.

What I found in logs is:

***Stack Dump being sent to C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\LOG\SQLDump0081.txt
SqlDumpExceptionHandler: Process 4788 generated fatal exception c0000005 EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION. SQL Server i
s terminating this process.

Whole log can be seen at: http://kabl.org/files/SQLDump0081.txt

second crash log made second later at: http://kabl.org/files/SQLDump0082.txt

I have analyzed mini crashdump with Microsoft tools, but no promising results. If it can help, here it is: http://kabl.org/files/SQLDump0081.mdmp

Any ideas are greatly welcome, since it is becoming quite a pain in the ass to restart server almost every day :)

Regrads,
-Matija

Comment: Can you post the dump files back up somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

What was the result of your crashdump analysis?  C0000005 errors are buffer overrun errors.   Since you have other instances running I would expect that the minidump analysis to show that there is a driver that's causing the issues.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Jim, it really must be related to memory overflows. I have analyzed minidump again, but nothing new came up. Snap can be seen at this image: http://kabl.org/files/crashdump.png

Comment: The only thing that comes to mind next is to change the server to do a full dump to see what application is following the rules. if it turns out that its sql (which I supose is possible) it's time to call Microsoft as you'd have found a bug